# Where is the reputation list required for permissions to do stuff on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, privileges-page

I would like to know how many reputation points I need to perform each possible task in Stack Overflow. Is there a publicly available page on Stack Overflow from where I can get this information?

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: It is a support question on Meta, so I would request the community not to downvote this post.

Comment: Just hover your mouse over your username on topbar. It will show you privileges link for particular site.

Comment: too late man, users these days are very intolerant :(

Comment: This is something I initially struggled to find, hovering over a button to get a different response to clicking the button is not a natural response. Especially when the hover over doesn't happen immediately, its easy to click that button a hundred times without ever seeing the dropdown

Comment: @EASI exact reps required for each task is displayed on mouse hover. Other option is to click on each task.

Comment: @RichardTingle Now the new [help] shows this link ("View a full list of privileges you can earn") on the main page.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Thats certainly an improvement then, weird that theres both a "Reputation and Privileges" and a "Privileges" section

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) page, you can find the privileges page through the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) or by hovering your mouse over your name.

On the page itself you see a list of all the privileges you can earn and the progress of every privilege. When you click on a privilege you will see how much reputation is needed to require this privilege. Also you will get a full explanation what feautures you will gain when you get the required rep.

Answer (score 3):

Please click on the `down arrow` near your `Name` display. Then click on the `Privileges` link on the popped window.

[image: Privileges]